# ERROR: whitelist file not found While Compiling Linux Kernel

Tags: kernel, compiling, make

I am trying to compile the latest kernel `linux-5.12` on my ubuntu 20.04.1. I have installed the necessary dependencies `sudo apt install build-essential rsync gcc bc bison libssl-dev libncurses5-dev libelf-dev` and copied the config file `cp /boot/config - $(uname -r) ./.config` to my location.

On executing this command `make deb-pkg` , I am getting the following error and even I tried online solutions nothing worked for me. Pl help me to solve this.

Thankyou

```
make clean
  CLEAN   arch/x86/tools
sh ./scripts/package/mkdebian
  TAR     linux-5.12.0.tar.gz
origversion=$(dpkg-parsechangelog -SVersion |sed 's/-[^-]*$//');\
    mv linux-5.12.0.tar.gz ../linux-5.12.0_${origversion}.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-buildpackage -r"fakeroot -u" -a$(cat debian/arch)  -i.git -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package linux-5.12.0
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 5.12.0-1
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution focal
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by amulbhatia <amulbhatia@amulbhatia>
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source -i.git --before-build .
 debian/rules clean
rm -rf debian/*tmp debian/files
make clean
 dpkg-source -i.git -b .
dpkg-source: info: using source format '1.0'
dpkg-source: warning: source directory 'linux-5.12' is not <sourcepackage>-<upstreamversion> 'linux-5.12.0-5.12.0'
dpkg-source: warning: .orig directory name linux-5.12.orig is not <package>-<upstreamversion> (wanted linux-5.12.0-5.12.0.orig)
dpkg-source: info: building linux-5.12.0 using existing linux-5.12.0_5.12.0.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: building linux-5.12.0 in linux-5.12.0_5.12.0-1.diff.gz
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file .scmversion
dpkg-source: warning: the diff modifies the following upstream files: 
 .clang-format
 .cocciconfig
 .config.old
 .get_maintainer.ignore
 .mailmap
 CREDITS
 MAINTAINERS
 README
dpkg-source: info: use the '3.0 (quilt)' format to have separate and documented changes to upstream files, see dpkg-source(1)
dpkg-source: info: building linux-5.12.0 in linux-5.12.0_5.12.0-1.dsc
dpkg-source: warning: missing information for output field Standards-Version
 debian/rules binary
make KERNELRELEASE=5.12.0 ARCH=x86  KBUILD_BUILD_VERSION=1 -f ./Makefile
  SYSHDR  arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h
  SYSHDR  arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_64.h
  SYSHDR  arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_x32.h
  SYSTBL  arch/x86/include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h
  SYSHDR  arch/x86/include/generated/asm/unistd_32_ia32.h
  SYSHDR  arch/x86/include/generated/asm/unistd_64_x32.h
  SYSTBL  arch/x86/include/generated/asm/syscalls_64.h
  HYPERCALLS arch/x86/include/generated/asm/xen-hypercalls.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o
  HOSTCC  arch/x86/tools/relocs_64.o
  HOSTCC  arch/x86/tools/relocs_common.o
  HOSTLD  arch/x86/tools/relocs
  HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/genksyms.o
  YACC    scripts/genksyms/parse.tab.[ch]
  HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/parse.tab.o
  LEX     scripts/genksyms/lex.lex.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/lex.lex.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/genksyms/genksyms
  HOSTCC  scripts/selinux/genheaders/genheaders
  HOSTCC  scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp
  HOSTCC  scripts/bin2c
  HOSTCC  scripts/kallsyms
  HOSTCC  scripts/sorttable
  HOSTCC  scripts/asn1_compiler
  HOSTCC  scripts/sign-file
  HOSTCC  scripts/extract-cert
  HOSTCC  scripts/insert-sys-cert
  GEN     include/generated/autoksyms.h

ERROR: '/home/amulbhatia/Desktop/linux_kernel/linux-5.12/y' whitelist file not found
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1189: include/generated/autoksyms.h] Error 1
make[2]: *** [debian/rules:7: build-arch] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.package:77: deb-pkg] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1579: deb-pkg] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the possible answer of the above issue. Though the answer may not be the direct answer.

I took the stable release `linux-5.11.6` from `kernel.org` and is compiled successfully.

`linux-5.12` is mainline version, may be is missing some of the files, as the same is not a stable release as on day.

- Please advise me to update the answer, if you find anything more relevant for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You had the right answer but the OS missed something try uninstalling those packages and reinstalling them. I had the same probelm on my system and did "sudo apt install build-essential rsync gcc bc bison libssl-dev libncurses5-dev libelf-dev" and it fixed it so it might be a missing package. Hope that helps.